# Logstash "sql_last_value" value comparizon is now working properly with GT condition

Tags: jdbc, sequelize.js, logstash, opensearch

I'd like to make a data pipeline composed with **RDS(Aurora DB), Logstash and AWS Opensearch.**

To make my opensearch index get a **Data Consistency**, I'd like to remove duplicated value with query.

For that, I wrote a logstash's config file like this.

```json
input{
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/ubuntu/logstash-7.16.2/bin/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://~~~~?useSSL=false"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "~~~~~~"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    tracking_column => "updated_at"
    use_column_value => true
    record_last_run => true
    tracking_column_type => “timestamp”
    schedule => "*/10 * * * * *"
    statement => "select * from my_table where updated_at > :sql_last_value order by updated_at ASC"
    jdbc_default_timezone => "Asia/Seoul"
  }
}

output {
  opensearch{
    hosts => "https://~~~~~:443"
    user => "admin"
    password => "~~~~~"
    index => "index"
    ecs_compatibility => disabled
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
  }
}
```

And the generated queries by logstash are these.

```bash
[2022-12-29T16:48:40,299][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001157s) SELECT version()
[2022-12-29T16:48:40,302][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001163s) SELECT version()
[2022-12-29T16:48:40,306][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001221s) SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM (select * from my_table where updated_at > '2022-12-28 22:31:05' order by updated_at ASC) AS `t1` LIMIT 1
[2022-12-29T16:48:40,309][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001166s) SELECT * FROM (select * from my_table where updated_at > '2022-12-28 22:31:05' order by updated_at ASC) AS `t1` LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 0
[2022-12-29T16:48:50,172][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001303s) SELECT version()
[2022-12-29T16:48:50,174][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001152s) SELECT version()
[2022-12-29T16:48:50,178][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001382s) SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM (select * from my_table where updated_at > '2022-12-28 22:31:05' order by updated_at ASC) AS `t1` LIMIT 1
[2022-12-29T16:48:50,182][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][0bb20d034a10be3c1a48635cda2cc7dfcb97e29fb63940352f5380ec253dfe48] (0.001153s) SELECT * FROM (select * from my_table where updated_at > '2022-12-28 22:31:05' order by updated_at ASC) AS `t1` LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 0
```

It looks like that everything is fine.
Sql_last_value was updated whenever a new data was inserted.

However, the values queried in opensearch also contain values that are equal to sql_last_value and updated_at.

For example,

```json
sql_last_value = 2022.12.08 12:12:12

first data : 2022.12.08 12:12:11
second data : 2022.12.08 12:12:12
third data : 2022.12.08 12:12:13
```

In above case, second and third one was selected by my query.
Also, sql_last_value was updated to **2022.12.08 12:12:13** from the next query.

And, **updated_at** column is created by Sequelize Module in NestJS (it is timestamp type).

What is the problem of my config file??

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how this works, but I solved the problem.

The problem was my statement query, **select * from my_table where updated_at > :sql_last_value order by updated_at ASC**.

I edited it to **select * from my_table where updated_at > :sql_last_value** without **order by** command.